# DPR-ERR-2002 While Connection Cognos 10.2.1 with Hive 0.11

Tags: jdbc, hive, cognos-10

I am new to Cognos and trying to connect Apache Hive 0.11 to visualize the data which is in Hadoop. I am using JDBC connectivity for doing this. While trying to connect these two systems, I got the following error,

```
DPR-ERR-2002 Unable to execute the request because there were no connections to the process available within the configured time limit
```

I also tried by changing the default `Queue time limit of the report service (seconds)` from default to 600 seconds in Cognos server Administration. But still the error persists. Can anyone tell me on what I need to do for connecting these two technologies or to resolve this error.